# How do I place the page number further to the border of the page with fancyhdr?

Tags: fancyhdr

I want to place the page number further into the corner of the outer page. The default placement in `fancyhdr` is too near to the text for my purposes. Ideally, I want the center of the page numbering have 1-centimeter distance to the outer border of the page and 1-centimeter to the lower border of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the page number in a LaTeX `picture` environment. E.g.

```
\fancyfoot[RO]{\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}%
              \begin{picture}(0,0)
                \put(<x>,-<y>){\thepage}
                \end{picture}}
```

And find out proper values for `<x>` and `<y>`. And similar for the left pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this command in the preambule

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength\footskip{5cm}
```

And its twin `\setlength\headheight{5cm}`

Put the desired length in the units you want: `12pt`,`7mm`,...

Comment: This does bring it to the lower border. It's however still not at the outer border.